# Google Assistant News are being emailed to me in the wrong language - how to fix?

Tags: settings, google, languages

I'm traveling and my Android phone's Google Assistant is now set to understand two languages, which is fine.

What's not fine: Google suddenly decided to **email me all the info in the second language which is not English**.

The emails are coming from the assistant-noreply@google.com address, so there's no way I can just reply and ask them...

I don't mind the emails, but **I want them to be in English**. Yet, they are coming exclusively in the second language. Drives me nuts. How do I fix this situation?